# Yii2 unable to get response from the API using postman

Tags: php, api, rest, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am working on `yii2` and created some `REST API's. One is for authenticating the user and the second one is for getting the data by using the` auth key`from the 1st API. I am using`xampp` on the local machine. The authenticate API is working perfectly alright. But when I am trying to execute the 2nd API it's giving me an error. Below is my code

**main.php**

```
<?php

$params = array_merge(
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);

 return [
'id' => 'app-api',
'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),    
'bootstrap' => ['log'],
'modules' => [
    'v1' => [
        'basePath' => '@app/modules/v1',
        'class' => 'api\modules\v1\Module'
    ]
],
'components' => [
    'request' => [
        'csrfParam' => '_csrf-backend',

        'enableCookieValidation' => false,
        'enableCsrfValidation' => false,
    ],
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => false,
    ],
    'log' => [
        'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
        'targets' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'enableStrictParsing' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                'controller' => ['v1/survey'],
                'tokens'=>[
                    '{id}' => '<id:\\d[\\d,]*>'
                ],
                'extraPatterns' => [
                    'POST add' => 'add',
                    'POST photo/save'=>'savepic',
                    'POST modify/{id}' => 'modify',
                    'GET refdata' => 'refdata',
                    'GET refdata.json' => 'refdatajson',
                    'GET shahid' => 'shahid',
                    'GET list' => 'list',

                ],
                'pluralize' => false
            ],[
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                'controller' => ['v1/issue'],
                'extraPatterns' => [
                    'POST add' => 'add'
                ],
                'pluralize' => false
            ],[
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                'controller' => ['v1/auth'],
                'extraPatterns' => [
                    'POST authenticate' => 'authenticate'
                ],
                'pluralize' => false
            ]
            , [
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                'controller' => ['v1/auth'],
                'extraPatterns' => [
                    'POST authenticate2' => 'authenticate2'
                ],
                'pluralize' => false
            ],[
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                'controller' => ['v1/team'],
                'extraPatterns' => [
                    'POST list' => 'list'
                ],
                'pluralize' => false
            ],
            [
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                'controller' => ['v1/installation'],
                'extraPatterns' => [
                    'GET list' => 'items',
                    'POST add' => 'addnew',
                    'POST photo/save' =>'savephoto',
                    'GET loadsurveyimages' =>'loadsurveyimages',
                    'GET listinstall'=>'listinstall',
                    'GET loadinstallationimages' => 'loadinstallationimages',
                    'GET loadfiles'=>'loadfiles',
                    'POST email' =>'email',
                    'GET details' =>'details',
                    'GET simtransfer'=>'simtransfer',
                    'POST metertosimmap'=>'metertosimmap',
                    'GET meterping'=>'meterping',
                    //'GET simtransfer'=>'simtransfer',
                ],
                'pluralize' => false
            ],
            [
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                'controller' => ['v1/preinstallation'],
                'extraPatterns' => [
                    'GET list' => 'items',
                    'POST add' => 'addnew',
                    'POST photo/save' =>'savephoto',
                    'GET loadsurveyimages' =>'loadsurveyimages',
                    'GET listinstall'=>'listinstall',
                    'GET loadinstallationimages' => 'loadinstallationimages',
                    'GET loadfiles'=>'loadfiles',
                    'GET email' =>'email',
                    'GET details' =>'details',
                    'GET refs' => 'refs',
                ],
                'pluralize' => false
            ],
            [
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                'controller' => ['v1/routes'],
                'extraPatterns' => [
                    'GET list' => 'list',
                    'GET meters'=>'meters',
                    'GET refs' => 'refs',
                    'GET ref' => 'ref',
                    'POST status'=>'status'
                ],
                'pluralize' => false
            ]
        ],        
    ]
],
'params' => $params,
];
```

The Authenticate API is working.

[image]

For all other API we have to use this secret key to access data and do other operations as well.

When I try to access it I am getting the below error

```
{
  "name": "Unauthorized",
  "message": "Your request was made with invalid credentials.",
  "code": 0,
  "status": 401,
  "type": "yii\\web\\UnauthorizedHttpException"
}
```

[image]

I have already used all the options under `body` of the postman. Also used `Params` and `Authorization` but nothing seems to work.

**.htaccess**

```
#SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

**Base Controller**

```
class BaseController extends ActiveController
{
/**
 * Activate Bear Authentication
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function behaviors()
{

    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

    $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
        'class' => HttpBearerAuth::className(),
    ];

    return $behaviors;
}
```

}

**HttpBearerAuth**

```
class HttpBearerAuth extends HttpHeaderAuth
{
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public $header = 'Authorization';
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
            */
public $pattern = '/^Bearer\s+(.*?)$/';
/**
 * @var string the HTTP authentication realm
 */
public $realm = 'api';


/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function challenge($response)
{

    $response->getHeaders()->set('WWW-Authenticate', "Bearer realm=\"{$this->realm}\"");

}
 }
```

I have already tried with  `SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0`. But still, the issue is there.

How to get rid of this issue? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @giò right now I can't switch.

Comment: Your post request in postman looks already wrong. You have to use the Authorization Header. Why do you put the auth_key as post value in the request? It should be Authorization Bearer According to your setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For HttpBearerAuth set token in header like
`Authorization: Bearer {token}`

For postman use `Authorization` tab and select type of token here:
[image: postman bearer]

And the token is automatically substituted into the headers (you can see if you display auto-generated headers)
[image]